# Setting size of mobile app using HTML & Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm building a phone app that allows users to drag shapes onto another "droppable" div, however I've run into a slight issue.

I am able to drag the shape outside of the application screen and continue dragging it further and further down or right of the original body div.

How would I lock the screen dimensions to a set width and height so the user cannot drag the shape outside of the actual application "screen"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`viewport` `meta` tags](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Hmm, added this line to the head tag of my HTML and it still doesn't work. Infact, it makes the interface much larger.

Comment: Show us your code, then. Yes, this will make the interface larger, as without this meta tag the page gets shrunk down to fix. When making a phone app, you should always **start** with this tag and design accordingly.